# Can I change and how to change REVTYPE values in Hibernate Envers?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I'm new in Hiberante and Envers. I successfully implemented Hibernate Envers in my application and made audited tables and everything works fine but I'm wondering is it possible to change values in REVTYPE column in audited tables.

For now I have values 0 (ADD), 1 (MOD) and 2 (DEL). I want to know is it possible to change this values, I want to change for 0 to be for example INSERT, 1 UPDATE and 2 DELETE.

Is this possible and how?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

This is not possible right now, except for forking the project and changing the code.